# How to use a Timer to slow a for-loop down

Tags: java, for-loop, timer, buffer

In making a for loop, I would like to control how long it takes to 'refresh' the loop, and I figured I could do this with a timer.
My only problem is the Timer keeps running like a for loop - repeating and repeating and repeating - so it just keeps the for loop from repeating, which is not what I want.
My for loop code is here:

```
for(int i=0; i < 200; i += 4){
    System.out.println("Hopefully will only run once...per 5 secs");
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }, 
        5000 // 5 sec buffer, but never stops buffering
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're looking for something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < 200; i += 4){
    System.out.println("Hopefully will only run once...per 5 secs");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's a nice, simple solution but the thread sleeps and doesn't do anything useful for most of the time. That's fine for most cases, but a more efficient solution would be to use a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), which is like the Timer you tried, only more modern.

Here's a rough sketch of how that might work:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    int j = i.getAndAdd(4);
    if (j >= 200) {
        exec.shutdownNow();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(j); //Will print 0,4,8 etc.. Once every 5 seconds
    //Do stuff
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: `scheduleAtFixedRate` is indeed the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside your `for-loop`

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```